# If $A$ is a set with $m$ elements and $C \subseteq A$ is a set with $1$ element, then prove that $A \setminus C$ is a set with $m-1$ elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Definition:** $N_m$ = $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$

**My Attempt:**
Since $A$ is a set with $m \in \mathbb{N}$ elements, there exists a bijection $f:N_m \to A$. We know that $C \subseteq A$ contains just $1$ element, say $a$ (**Note that $a \in A$ as well**). Let $k \in N_m$ be the element that maps to $a$. We know $k$ is unique because $f$ is also an injection.

We define:
$$h(q)=
\begin{cases}
f(q),&q=1,2,\ldots,k-1 \\[2ex]
f(q+1),&q=k,k+1,\ldots,m-1
\end{cases}$$

It is evident that $h:N_{m-1} \to A\setminus C$. All we have to do now is to prove that **$h$ is a bijection**.

- **Injectivity:** There are only two possible scenarios for any member of the domain. Either it belongs to $N_{k-1}$ or it belongs to $N_{m-1} \setminus N_{k-1}$.

  1. For any $x_1,x_2 \in N_{k-1}$ such that $x_1 \neq x_2$, $h(x_1),h(x_2) \in f(N_{k-1})$. Since $f$ is injective over $N_{k-1}$, $h(x_1) \neq h(x_2)$.
  2. For any $x_1,x_2 \in N_{m-1} \setminus N_{k-1}$ such that $x_1 \neq x_2$, $h(x_1),h(x_2) \in f(N_{m-1} \setminus N_{k-1})$. Since $f$ is injective over $N_{m-1} \setminus N_{k-1}$, $h(x_1) \neq h(x_2)$.
- **Surjectivity:** This is the part I cannot figure out. I would like if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any element $y\in A\setminus C$. Since $f$ is a bijection, we know that there exists $x_y\in \mathbb{N}_m$ such that $f(x_y) = y$. If $x_y < k$, then $x_y \in \Bbb N_{m-1}$ is such that $h(x_y) = f(x_y) = y$. If $k < x_y \leq m$, then $x_y -1 \in \Bbb N_{m-1}$ is such that $h(x_y - 1) = f(x_y - 1 + 1) = f(x_y) = y$. So for all $y \in A\setminus C$, there is an element $n\in \Bbb N_{m-1}$ such that $h(n) = y$.

Comment: My function takes $k$ in the domain. Your proof does not equate $x_a$ with $k$ anywhere.

Comment: $x_a$ cannot be $k$, since $k$ is mapped to the element in $C$ and $a$ is an element of $A\setminus C$. Remember, you want to show that for all $a\in A\setminus C$, there is an element of $\Bbb N_{m-1}$ such that $h$ maps that element to $a$. This is exactly what I have shown.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Yes, $x_a$ cannot be $k$ but $q$ can be.

Comment: If you are talking about the argument $q$ of $h$, then yes, $q$ can be $k$. In that case, we have $h(k) = f(k+1) = a$, where $a$ is an element of $A\setminus C$. This is the case $x_a -1 = k$, which I have dealt with in the case $k < x_a \leq m$.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi I've replaced the $a$'s with $y$'s as you suggested, in case that was confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

Be $b\in A\setminus C$. Since $b\in A$ and $f$ is an injection, there exists a $q$ such that $f(q)=b$, and clearly $q \ne k$. Therefore either $q>k$ or $q<k$. Can you continue from there?

Comment: But $q=k$ according to the function I defined.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi: I think you've been confused by my re-using the name $a$ for an element *not* in $A$. Sorry about that; I'll edit the post.

Comment: According to my definition, $f$ maps $N_m$ onto $A$. You took $q \in A$ and put that in the domain of $f$. I am confused.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi: Oops, no wonder; in my comment I confused $A$ and $C$. Of course the element is in $A$. I meant it is not in $C$ (you — also somewhat confusingly — gave the element in $C$ the name $a$). And in my post I also got a $q$ where it didn't belong (indeed, it was used before I introduced it). I'll edit again. Sorry about all the confusion. I also noticed that I mixed up the $A$ and $C$ in the beginning of the post; now also corrected.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $x\in A\setminus C$. Then in particular $x\in A$. Therefore $$\exists y\in N_m\ | \ \ f(y)=x$$

Comment: You implied that "$\exists y \in N_m$" but don't we need to show that "$\exists y \in N_{m-1}$"? I need you to reason out that part. :)